# Shared preferences always returns the same value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working on an Android application, where there are 2 types of users. When the user signs up or logs into the system, they are redirected to the same Home Screen, and see different view fragment inflated based on their type. I was able to achieve this using Shared Preferences during first time sign up. My only problem is that, if the user signs out and then tries to login again, the matter what type of user he is, the same home screen is loaded. I doubt, the Activity uses the last set Shared preferences.

In my fragment, based on the userType, I inflate the corresponding xml file. My requirement is, when the user signs in, how to I inflate the corresponding xml file ie. how do I get the Shared preferences in SignInActivity to load the corresponding fragment xml.

Here is what I have tried so far.

**MainMenuActivity.java**

```
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    gaFragmentStack = new Stack<>();

    Fragment home_fragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, home_fragment);
    transaction.commit();

    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (getUid() != null) {
        String userId = getUid();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);

    } else {
        onAuthFailure();
    }

    final PrimaryDrawerItem home = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Home").withIdentifier(1).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_home);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem profile = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Profile").withIdentifier(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_account);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem gallery = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Gallery").withIdentifier(3).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_perm_media_black_24dp);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem recognition = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Recognition").withIdentifier(4).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_face);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem maps = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Maps").withIdentifier(5).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_black_24dp);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem tagAndLocate = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Tag & Locate").withIdentifier(6).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem gamesAndPuzzle = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Games & Puzzles").withIdentifier(7).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_casino_black_24dp);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem backup = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Backup").withIdentifier(8).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_save);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem logout = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Logout").withIdentifier(9).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_sign_out);

    DrawerImageLoader.init(new AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(imageView);
        }
    });

    String name = preferences.getString(Preferences.NAME, "");
    String email = preferences.getString(Preferences.EMAIL, "");
    final ProfileDrawerItem userProfile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(name).withEmail(email).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_white_24dp);

    headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
            .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
            .addProfiles(userProfile)
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();

    String userType = preferences.getString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, "");

    if(userType !=null && userType.equalsIgnoreCase("Standard")) {

        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(false)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .addDrawerItems(home)
                .addDrawerItems(profile)
                .addDrawerItems(gallery)
                .addDrawerItems(recognition)
                .addDrawerItems(maps)
                .addDrawerItems(tagAndLocate)
                .addDrawerItems(gamesAndPuzzle)
                .addDrawerItems(backup)
                .addDrawerItems(new DividerDrawerItem())
                .addDrawerItems(logout)
                .buildForFragment();

        result.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                int drawItemId = (int) drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                Intent intent;
                Fragment fragment;
                switch (drawItemId) {

                    case 1:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(home);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(profile);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(gallery);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        fragment = new RecognitionFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(recognition);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        fragment = new MapsFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(maps);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        fragment = new TagLocateFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(tagAndLocate);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        fragment = new GamesPuzzlesFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(gamesAndPuzzle);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        fragment = new BackupFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(backup);
                        break;
                    default:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                }
                if (drawItemId == 9) {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                    intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }else {
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(false)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .addDrawerItems(home)
                .addDrawerItems(profile)
                .addDrawerItems(maps)
                .addDrawerItems(backup)
                .addDrawerItems(new DividerDrawerItem())
                .addDrawerItems(logout)
                .buildForFragment();


        result.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                int drawItemId = (int) drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                Intent intent;
                Fragment fragment;
                switch (drawItemId) {

                    case 1:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(home);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(profile);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        fragment = new MapsFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(maps);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        fragment = new BackupFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(backup);
                        break;
                    default:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                }
                if (drawItemId == 9) {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                    intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**SignInActivity.java**

```
{

    String email;

    if(view.getId() == R.id.loginButton){
        email = emailLoginTextInputEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordLoginEditText.getText().toString();

        if (!validateEmail(email)) {
            return;
        }
        if (!validateSetPass(password)) {
            return;
        }
        showProgressDialog("Signing in...");
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            hideProgressDialog();
                            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(getUid());
                            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    Profile profile = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
                                    Log.e("key", dataSnapshot.getKey());
                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SignInActivity.this);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                    if(profile !=null){
                                        editor.putString(Preferences.EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
                                        editor.putString(Preferences.NAME, profile.getFullName());
                                    }
                                    editor.putString(Preferences.USERID, getUid());
                                    editor.apply();

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,MainMenuActivity.class);
                            loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(loginIntent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.singinGoogleButton)
    {
        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Signing in with google...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.signupTV)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    else if (view.getId() == R.id.forgotPasswordTextView) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,ResetPasswordActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        }
    }
```

**SignUpActivity.java**

```
{

    showProgressDialog("Saving...");
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String fullName = intent.getStringExtra("fullName");
    String userEmailAddress = intent.getStringExtra("emailAddress");
    String userType = intent.getStringExtra("userType");

    String phoneNumber = phoneNumberTextInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String dateOfBirth = dateofBirthTextInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String securityAnswer = securityAnswerTextInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!validateForm(phoneNumber, dateOfBirth, securityAnswer)) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        return;
    }

    if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("Standard")){
        hideProgressDialog();
        Toast.makeText(this, "User details saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent guardianIntent = new Intent(ContactDetailsActivity.this, AddGuardianActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        guardianIntent.putExtra("fullName", fullName);
        guardianIntent.putExtra("userEmailAddress", userEmailAddress);
        guardianIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        guardianIntent.putExtra("dateofBirth", dateOfBirth);
        guardianIntent.putExtra("userType", userType);
        guardianIntent.putExtra("securityAnswer", securityAnswer);
        guardianIntent.putExtra("securityQuestion", securityQuestion);
        startActivity(guardianIntent);
        finish();
    }else{
        databaseReference.child("fullName").setValue(fullName);
        databaseReference.child("phoneNumber").setValue(phoneNumber);
        databaseReference.child("dateOfBirth").setValue(dateOfBirth);
        databaseReference.child("securityAnswer").setValue(securityAnswer);
        databaseReference.child("securityQuestion").setValue(securityQuestion);
        databaseReference.child("userType").setValue(userType);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Profile profile = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ContactDetailsActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                if(profile != null) {
                    editor.putString(Preferences.NAME, profile.getFullName());
                    editor.putString(Preferences.EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
                    editor.putString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, profile.getUserType());
                }
                editor.putString(Preferences.USERID, getUid());
                editor.apply();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        hideProgressDialog();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent mainMenuIntent = new Intent(ContactDetailsActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
        mainMenuIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(mainMenuIntent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String userType = sharedPreferences.getString(Preferences.USER_TYPE, "");
    View view;
    if(userType != null && userType.equalsIgnoreCase("STANDARD")) {

         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }else{
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_guardian, container, false);
    }
    toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.homeScreen));
    initControls(view,userType);
    return view;
}
```

When the user signs in to the app, how to I load the respective fragment xml? What am I missing? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting SharedPreference instances using `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` but with different context each time .

Use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `Activity.this` or `this`.